# Finding duplicates, concatenating and adding text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am working with a 7.5K dataset of email addresses and the name of the list they are in and I need to format the list name in a JSON array `["apples","bananas","oranges"]`.

I used `=countif(A:A,A1)>1` and colour to see the duplicates. But how do I combine the list name and have `["list 1","list 2"]` from cell B2 if there is a duplicate?

Current data:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| email 1 | list 1 |
| email 1 | list 2 |
| email 2 | list 1 |
| email 2 | list 2 |

I want it:

| email 1 | ["list 1","list 2"] |
| --- | --- |

Comment: Sorry I am using Google Sheets

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(REGEXREPLACE(TEXT(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 QUERY(QUERY({A:A&"×", IF(B:B="",, B:B&",")}, 
 "select max(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null
  group by Col2
  pivot Col1"),,9^9)), "×")), {"@", "\[@\]"}), ";]", "]"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply and for the formula. I am getting an error Error
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in D2.

Comment: @Faraz delete range D2:D. its arrayformula type formula = it auto-calculates for all rows = no need to drag it = it needs to have a "space" to "roll out"

Comment: Duh, I see it now :)  thank you soo much player0 this really saved me